# No results returned for elseif PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a database with a 'status' column which either reads 'active' or 'inactive'.

I'd like to return different text depending on whether the status is 'active' or 'inactive', and I'm using `if...` and `elseif...` for this.

If the status is 'active', the message is displaying perfectly. This also prompts the database to update the status field to 'inactive' - again, this is working perfectly.

But if I reload the page, using a key for which I know the status is 'inactive', nothing displays.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['key'])) {
    $key = $_GET['key'];

    include("db.php");

    $download_query="SELECT * FROM sales WHERE key='$key'";
    $download_result=@mysql_query($download_query);
    $download_row=@mysql_fetch_array($download_result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $productid=$download_row['productid'];
    $datecreated=$download_row['datecreated'];
    $dateaccessed=$download_row['dateaccessed'];
    $status=$download_row['status'];

    if ($status=="active") {
        $download_updatestatus_query="UPDATE `sales` SET `status`='inactive' WHERE `key`='$key'";
        $download_updatestatus_result=@mysql_query($download_updatestatus_query) or die (mysql_error());
        echo "Go ahead and download file.";
    }
    else if ($status=="inactive") {
        echo "You may have downloaded this before.";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Sorry, no key provided.";
}

?>
```

Comment: Try var_dump($status) before all if's. What do you see?

Comment: try to remove `@` from your code, some errors should come up.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are surpressing errors?

Comment: Also indent your code to see what is going on.

Comment: @Nazariy Here's the error message I'm getting: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/martinj/public_html/download.php on line 10.

Comment: @Martin so you probably don't get valid $key into query.

Comment: your problem isnt with elsif. your not getting results from sql. Try the mysql error function to find out whats up http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: @wikp I'm getting 'NULL' in addition to that warning message above.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` after your elseif. try:

```
else if ($status=="inactive") {
echo "You may have downloaded this before.";
}

else {
```

Comment: It is a bracket for previous if :)

Comment: sry. a properly nested structure helps with that :)

Comment: @Martin can you try using the mysql_error function to output the error sql is getting?

Answer (score 0):

You suppose to make sure that `mysql_query` is not false and contains some results by running `mysql_num_rows` before you start fetching data.

Also passing `$_GET` value to MySQL Query without validation is very bad idea.

```
if (isset($_GET['key']))
{
    //You have to make sure that provided value is safe to use in mysql query
    $key = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['key']);

    include("db.php");

    $download_query = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE key='$key'";

    $download_result = mysql_query($download_query);

    // Check result
    if (!$download_result)
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

    if($download_result && mysql_num_rows($download_result) > 0)
    {
        $download_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($download_result);
        $productid = $download_row['productid'];
        $datecreated = $download_row['datecreated'];
        $dateaccessed = $download_row['dateaccessed'];
        $status = $download_row['status'];

        if ($status == "active")
        {
            $download_updatestatus_query = "UPDATE `sales` SET `status`='inactive' WHERE `key`='$key'";

            $download_updatestatus_result = mysql_query($download_updatestatus_query) or die (mysql_error());

            echo "Go ahead and download file.";
        }
        else if ($status == "inactive")
        {
            echo "You may have downloaded this before.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'No results found';
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry, no key provided.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Nazariy. That's getting the 'No results found message', rather than 'NULL'. But the key specified in the URL definitely exists in the DB and definitely has a status of 'inactive'. I'm also getting the error message: `Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/martinj/public_html/download.php on line 13.`

Comment: I have added basic validation

Comment: The key is a random combination of numbers, letters and punctuation and is 12 characters long. I've just seen your comment about $_GET. If it wouldn't be too much trouble, could you elaborate? It's a technique I've been using for a while but perhaps I shouldn't be!

Comment: Hi Nazariy. I'm getting the following with the code above: `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'martinj'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/martinj/public_html/download.php on line 6

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/martinj/public_html/download.php on line 6`

Comment: The problem must be in database connection, make sure that your script can access MySQL database, probably password is missing.

Comment: The database is able to pull results where the status is 'active' though. It's a weird one... but I'm glad it's not something obvious (well, sort of glad...!)